# Describing a differentiable bijective function

Tags: analysis

Describe a differentiable bijective function from $$\{(x, y) \in |\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$$ to $$\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\mid x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1, z < 1\}.$$

I'm not sure how the question wants me to lay this out or what it really wants with 'describe'. Can anyone provide any hints to help me start this?

Comment: You need to give a bijective differentiable function from the disc $\mathbb{D} ^2 $ to the lower hemisphere of $S^2 $

Comment: @Anon I think it's actually $S^2\setminus\{(0,0,1)\}$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes my mistake, I took the 1 as a 0.

Comment: By "describe" I think they mean that you don't have to give the explicit formula.  For example, stereographic projection from the punctured sphere to the plane comes into this, but we actually want the inverse mapping.  I guess they're saying that it's enough to show the inverse is differentiable, without giving the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to your question. Jacobs explicitly found a diffeomorphism between the two sets, hence a differentiable bijection.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2348911/334795

Your question is a very famous example that appears in topological manifold theory. We say that, from your sets, the latter is homeomorphic to the former. In fact, we can also say that it's diffeomorphic to the former in this case.